# Elasticsearch: Unexpected interaction between synonym_graph and stop filter in custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, stop-words, synonym

## Description

I'm tring to query with multi words synonym including a stop word.
Let's start with an exemple to explain.

I've got the following documents into a index.

- foo
- bar
- foo bar
- foo of bar
- fb

Expected result with the query `{"query":{"match":{"test":{"query":"foo of bar"}}}}` is to return documents:

- foo bar
- foo of bar
- fb

## configuration

In this exemple, I got 2 filters:

- stop: will remove the token **of**
- synonym_graph: handle synonymes **fb, foo bar, foo of bar**

### Mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "test_index_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "test_search_analyzer"
    }
}
```

### Settings

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "test_index_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "english_stop"
                        ]
                    },
                    "test_search_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "english_stop",
                            "english_syn"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": { 
                    "english_stop": {
                        "type": "stop",
                        "stopwords": "_english_",
                        "ignore_case": true,
                        "remove_trailing": false
                    },
                    "english_syn": {
                        "type": "synonym_graph",
                        "synonyms": [
                            "fb,foo of bar",
                            "fb,foo bar"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

> token format: "token,start_offset-end_offset,type / position / positionLength"

| Query | Search Result | index analysys | Search analysys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fb | fb | fb,0-2,word,0,1 | foo,0-2,SYNONYM / 0 / 1 foo,0-2,SYNONYM / 0 / 3 fb,0-2,word / 0 / 4 bar,0-2,SYNONYM / 2 / 2 bar,0-2,SYNONYM / 3 / 1 |
| foo of bar | fb | foo,0-3,word,0,1 bar,7-10,word,2,1 | fb,0-10,SYNONYM / 0 / 3 foo,0-3,word / 0 / 1 bar,7-10,word / 2 / 1 |
| foo bar | fb,foo bar | foo,0-3,word,0,1 bar,4-7,word,1,1 | fb,0-7,SYNONYM / 0 / 2 foo,0-3,word / 0 / 1 bar,4-7,word / 1 / 1 |

All search expect to return the 3 lines:

- fb
- foo bar
- foo of bar

Note: foo of bar is never returned

My guess is than **foo of bar** got indexed with position [foo, ,bar] by the stop filter and synonym is looking for [foo, bar].

Do you have any advice to reach my goal ?

Comment: I've found an open issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28838 (related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8137)

Comment: I've found a page that propose a solution: https://sease.io/2018/07/combining-synonyms-and-stopwords.html
But it needs to deploy a custom filter in Java and might be difficult to patch to production for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use stopwords filter the position of word will be kept so if you check the analyzer result for foo of bar you will get below result:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "foo",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "bar",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see you get 'foo' token in position of zero and 'bar' in position of two, so you synonym filter can't find this document.

To solve your problem you should first apply synonym filter and then remove stop words like below.

```
"test_search_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
      "english_syn",
      "english_stop"
    ]
  }
```

and you should add 'foo bar, foo of bar' to your synonym list.

In my opinion keeping stop word is necessary because it can help getting more precise search results(especially with BM25 similarity that ES uses.), you can check elastic search official article about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query).

Comment: synonym "fb,foo bar,foo of bar" and having stop filter at the end is giving this result:
- Search on "foo of bar" return documents "fb","foo bar"
- Search on "fb" return documents "fb","foo bar"
- Search on "foo bar" return documents "fb" only

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to dig into "Common Terms Query" event if it seams to be deprecated from version 7.3 of elasticsearch?

Comment: For information, removing stop words filter and having synonyme "fb,foo bar,foo of bar" return what is expected. But we need to check tuning regression as well as performance impact with a real dataset.

Comment: @Joan, I think match query will do same as "Common Terms query" based on using BM25 Similarity. For more info about BM25 check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25.